# Create new column with function in Spark Dataframe based on a string search of another column

Tags: python, function, text, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a spark dataframe with a column that contains string values (i.e. 'xyztext\afadfa'). I wish to create a new column where the values are '0' or '1' depending on whether the original column contains certain text (i.e. 'text')

Example of result:

```
## +---+---+------+---------+
## | x1| x2|   x3 | xnew    |
## +---+---+------+---------+
## |  1|  a| xtext|    1    |
## |  3|  B| abcht|    0    |
```

EDIT: I have tried this previously (and have now added .cast(int)) thanks to SGVD but receive 'column is not callable' error when I insert the column name:
    df1 = df.withColumn('Target', df.column.contains('text').cast('int'))

The best I have achieved so far is creating a column with 0's in it by:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df1 = df.withColumn('Target', lit(0))
```

I have also tried an if then else statement to create the vector but am having no luck:

```
 def targ(string):
     if df.column.contains('text'): return '1'
     else: return '0'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark columns have a `cast` method to cast between types, and you can cast a boolean type to an integer, where `True` is cast to `1` and `False` to `0`. In Scala, you could use `Column#contains` to check for a substring. PySpark does not have this method, but you can use the `instr` function instead:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1 = df.withColumn('Target', (F.instr(df.column, 'text') > 0).cast('int'))
```

You can also write this function as a SQL expression:

```
df1 = df.withColumn('Target', F.expr("INSTR(column, 'text') > 0").cast('int'))
```

Or, completely in SQL without the cast:

```
df1 = df.withColumn('Target', F.expr("IF(INSTR(column, 'text') > 0, 1, 0)"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you happen to know why I would keep getting this error when I insert the column name though? TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-df3641126966> in <module>()
----> 1 df2 = df1.withColumn('Target', df.csuristem.contains('text').cast('int'))

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: I wrongly assumed a Scala method was available in PySpark too. I have edited my answer with some actually working examples.